# String index out of range and can't find anything similar

Tags: java

I have to find the char which appears the least in a string.

```
package String2;

public class Methods3 {
  static final int chars=256;
  static char least(String str) {
    int[] bro=new int[chars];
    int j;

    //I made the frequency of chars:
    for(j=0 ; j<str.length() ; j++) {
      (bro[str.charAt(j)])++; //made the array
    }
    int min= bro[str.charAt(0)];

    //Tried finding the smallest value:
    for(int x=0 ; x<bro.length ; x++ ) {
        if((bro[str.charAt(x)])<=min) {
            min=(bro[str.charAt(x)]); //finding the smallest number of times 
        }
    }
    return (char) min;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt="yooooo bbaa ccoo";
    char rez=least(txt);
    System.out.println(rez);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what problem do you run into? And where does it occur?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 16 .this is the error i get

Comment: Of course you are getting this Exception. In the line `str.charAt(x)` x will be incremented until the length of `bro`, which is 256. But `str` has only a length of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to print "y", and your code is broken in many ways:

this fixes it a bit:

```
public class Methods3 {
    static final int chars = Character.MAX_VALUE;   
    static char least(String str) {    
        int[] bro = new int[chars];    
        int j;    
        for (j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {            
            (bro[str.charAt(j)])++; // made the array
        }
        int min = Character.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int x = 0; x < bro.length; x++) {
            if ((bro[x]) <= min && bro[x] > 0)  {
                min = x; // finding the smallest number of times
            }
        }

        return (char) min;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String txt = "yooooo bbaa ccoo";    
        char rez = least(txt);    
        System.out.println(rez);
    }
}
```

(fixed to use Character.MAX_VALUE as suggested). This will work with any string.

Please note that min must be initialized with the maximum value for your algorithm to work, hence min=Character.MAX_VALUE.

Where you used "bro[str.charAt(x)]" you had to use "bro[x]".

And in the if you need an extra condition "bro[x] > 0" to ignore chars you did not find.

Also if you have two letters with the same count it will print the last to appear in the string with the same minimum count.

Comment: next time try to formulate a question, don't put your code and let us guess ;-)

Comment: yeah I'll try next time. It's my first time posting here, didn't know that forums where people actually help exist.thx again

Comment: there is not robot giving answers ... yet, in a not so far future may be AI will do ;-)

Comment: "Chars are not always 1-byte wide in Java.": Characters are never one byte. See the [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class. Of course we use characters like €, don't we ? Also see [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE) and get rid of the 256.

Comment: you are right, I was keeping the changes to the minimum, but this is working with any string now.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are not one byte per symbol. Try to create `bro` array with length of `Character.MAX_VALUE` or use HashMap instead of array.

```
int[] bro=new int[Character.MAX_VALUE];
```

With Map

```
Map bro = new HashMap();
for(char cr : str.toCharArray()){
    bro.compute(cr, (key, val) -> val == null : 1 : val + 1);
}
```

Comment: I downvoted: how could it help? (OP exceeded `str.length()`)

Comment: Daniel is trying to calculate the number of different character in the source string and using for it an array with length 256 but characters in java not one bytes long. From my point of view that's the reason of index out of bounds error here.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem in your code is in:

```
bro[str.charAt(x)])
```

As the `bro` array is 256 long, x is also in the range of [0,256], but in your case you are indexing into the string `str` itself, which is not 256 long.

Also you are returning the min number of occurrences as a character, and not the character itself, in this case you have to return the key from the array not the value, in this case you need to return `x`.

Edited: You must also ignore all the character that don't appear at all in the string, in which case would always have a value of 0 and always be the min, despite not occurring.

Replace:

```
for(int x = 0; x < bro.length; x++) {
    if ((bro[str.charAt(x)]) <= min) {
        min = (bro[str.charAt(x)]); // finding the smallest number of times 
    }
}
return (char) min;
```

with:

```
for (int x = 0; x < bro.length; x++) {
    if ((bro[x]) <= min && bro[x] > 0) {
        min = x; // finding the smallest number of times 
    }
}
return (char) min;
```

Comment: Now it doesn't print anything

Comment: So now it return a strange y no matter what value i put into the string...

Answer (score 0):

```
String txt="yooooo bbaa ccoo";  // string length here
```

your string length index is in the range `0 <= x <= str.length -1` where as your for loop range is `0 <= x <= 255`.

in the for loop, `0 <= x <= 255`, see `str.charAt(x)`

```
if((bro[str.charAt(x)])<=min)
```

however,

```
str.length < 256  // that is the problem
```

`x` should be `0 <= x <= str.length -1`

Answer (score 0):

- add a method to return the number of times the parameter char occurs in the string
- initialise variable `minOccurences` with total number of chars
- create empty list to store chars with minimum number of occurences
- for each char in the string

  - call this method and get number of occurences
  - if `minOccurences` is greater than current number set it to current number, clear `minChars` and add the char
  - if `minOccurences` is equal to current number add the char